# Late 1960s-early1970s sci fi film following "and then there were none" plotline in a group of people cryogenically frozen to avoid a plague?

Tags: movie, story-identification

Over a decade ago, I watched a sci-fi movie but never saw the ending, and it has bugged me ever since.  The plot, as I remember it, is that there was a group of ~10 people who were cryogenically frozen during a period of extremely virulent disease with the hope that by the time they woke up, there would be a cure of some sort.  They wake up, and there is a cure, but there isn't enough cure for all of them.  Then people mysteriously start dying, one by one, in a manner reminiscent of Agatha Christie's "And then there were none".  There may also be a "house-computer" similar to the Star Trek computer that may or may not be involved - my memory is fuzzy on this point - and there are no other people alive or at least nearby.  I believe it was made in the late 60s or early 70s based on the set design and costuming (very similar to the original Star Trek TV show).  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I was thinking it might be The Outer Limits episode "The Vaccine"; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667987/ but AlanT's answer is clearly what you've described

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a Logan's Run episode, [*The Crypt.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0635128/?ref_=tt_ep_ep7)

> Logan, Jessica and Rem come across a civilization which was
>   devastated by the holocaust. They find a recording wherein they learn
>   that there was a plague that nearly wiped out everyone. But **6 were
>   chosen to rebuild what was destroyed and were kept in suspended
>   animation till a cure could be found. Fortunately a cure was found but
>   no one was left who could administer it**. So they ask whoever sees this
>   recording to bring the cure to them. They try but **an earthquake
>   destroys one of the two flasks.** They awake the six and when they learn
>   what happened only three of them can receive the cure. So they put it
>   in their hands to decide who should get the cure. And **while they try
>   to decide someone is killing the six one at a time**

Comment: Hmmm, that's not the episode where we find out that time-travel is what caused the World War which lead to the Logan-verse?!  Man that was an excellent show and if hadn't been for "late night re-reuns" I never would have caught it.

Comment: @AlanT. +1 as this was the episode that came to my mind from the description as well.  To Fza, no, it is a different episode in which the time travel occurs. That is: 
Episode 5 "Man Out of Time" Nicholas Colasanto Noah Ward 17 October 1977 
Scientist David Eakins time-travels 200 years into the future, where he encounters Logan, Jessica and Rem. He then plans to change history and prevent the nuclear war, but in the process he could erase the Runner world's existence.  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan's_Run_(TV_series)